# BASH - Correctly quoting a date command

Tags: bash

In the process of writing a bash script to parse a tab-separated file and unfortunately I need the ask the user for a date outside of the contents/creation of the file.  I've gotten everything working, *except* looping through badly entered dates from the user until they enter one matching the desired format.
My debug code-block is as follows...

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER_INPUT="01-01-2011" # ARBITRARILY ASSIGNING A BAD DATE BECAUSE I'M TOO LAZY TO TYPE ONE IN EACH TIME
EXPERIMENTDATE="$USER_INPUT"
if [[ $OSTYPE == *"linux"* ]]
then
    date -d \"$EXPERIMENTDATE\" +%Y-%m-%d > /dev/null  2>&1
else
    date -j -f \"%Y-%m-%d\" \"$EXPERIMENTDATE\" +%Y-%m-%d > /dev/null  2>&1
fi
is_valid="$?"
echo -e "$is_valid"
# FYI - $? RETURNS A BINARY FLAG ON THE LAST COMMAND'S EXECUTION. 1 IF ERROR, 0 IF NORMAL EXIT
while [ $is_valid -ne 0 ]; do
    echo -e "Invalid date entered. Please enter the day the experiement was conducted on, in exactly the following format. YYYY-MM-DD (e.g. 2011-04-22)"
    read USER_INPUT
    EXPERIMENTDATE=$USER_INPUT
    echo -e "You entered $EXPERIMENTDATE"
    if [[ $OSTYPE == *"linux"* ]]
    then
        echo -e "DEBUG: date -d \"$EXPERIMENTDATE\" +%Y-%m-%d > /dev/null 2>&1"
        date -d \"$EXPERIMENTDATE\" +%Y-%m-%d > /dev/null 2>&1
    else
        echo -e "DEBUG: date -j -f \"%Y-%m-%d\" \"$EXPERIMENTDATE\" +%Y-%m-%d > /dev/null  2>&1"
        date -j -f \"%Y-%m-%d\" \"$EXPERIMENTDATE\" +%Y-%m-%d > /dev/null  2>&1
    fi
    is_valid="$?"
    echo -e "DEBUG: $is_valid"
done
echo -e "You entered $EXPERIMENTDATE"
```

From the above, none of the date commands seem to evaluate correctly within the if's, but executing the debug commands directly on the CLI work. 
I'm sure this is going to be a quoting/back-tic deal, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: For future reference this was *entirely* too much code for the question asked. In the future please try harder to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or mcve.

Comment: To explain the why of it: `\"` creates a *literal quote character* -- that is to say, it's passing the quote itself to the `date` command; `\"` is is a single `"` as data, not syntax, so if you put `\"`s in, say, a format string passed to date, you'll get literal `"`s in `date`'s output. The point of syntactic quotes is to tell the **shell** how to expand and split things before passing them to the underlying command.

Comment: ...now, on some different points, you should avoid using `echo -e` -- see the POSIX spec for `echo` at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, including the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Comment: Also, if you want a "DEBUG print" where copy-and-pasting it will actually run the same thing as the command itself...  `printf 'DEBUG: '; printf '%q ' date -j -f \"%Y-%m-%d\" \"$EXPERIMENTDATE\" +%Y-%m-%d; printf '\n'`

Comment: On a different point -- don't use all-caps names for your own variables; those are reserved for environment variables and shell builtins. See the fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html for guidance on environment variable naming conventions, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Thanks for the tips, just converted all the (user) vars to lowercase and moved over to printf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape the quotes that aren't inside similar quotes. For example, not

```
date -j -f \"%Y-%m-%d\" \"$EXPERIMENTDATE\" +%Y-%m-%d > /dev/null  2>&1
```

but

```
date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" "$EXPERIMENTDATE" +%Y-%m-%d > /dev/null  2>&1
```

Comment: It's not necessarily accurate to imply that one always *can* escape quotes that are inside similar quotes. `'\''`, for instance, doesn't do what one might expect.

Comment: That was just a quickly worded statement to exclude the escaped double quotes in his debug message.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Was purposefully escaping the double-quotes, for some reason I thought date needed the input to be quoted off.

Comment: @Keiron, if `EXPERIMENTDATE` can contain spaces or glob characters, then you legitimately need syntactic quotes to keep it all passed as a single argument (and using them is good practice regardless). What you *don't* need is quotes as data passed to `date` itself.